# CSS animation won't stay in place after playing and plays more than once even after adding one iteration

Tags: html, css

just a beginner programmer looking for some help for a website. My goal was to be able to make the bottom image slide down so that the user could click the buttons and switch pages. I wanted the image to stay in its place after finishing the animation. I tried adding the animation-fillmode:forward and that worked but after adding the animation-iteration: 1 code it kept on playing on and on.

Welcome to any help and thank you,
Aidan Cheung

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>aidancheung.com</title>
</head>
<style>
 h1 {
  font-family: coolvetica;
  text-align: center;
}
 .bottom {
        position: absolute;
        top: 275px;
    }
    .bottom:hover img {
     position: absolute;
        -webkit-animation: floatBubble 2s  normal ease-out;
        animation: floatBubble 2s normal ease-out;
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

    }
    @-webkit-keyframes floatBubble {
        0% {
            top:275px;
        }
        50%{
           top: 500px;
        }
        100% {
            top:275px;
        }
    }
    @keyframes floatBubble {
        0% {
            top:275px;
        }
        50%{
           top: 500px;
        }
        100% {
            top:275px;
        }
    }
 
</style>
<img src="Website.png" alt="Top Building">
<h1 style="line-height:45px;font-size: 100px;">aidancheung.<br><i style="font-size: 50px">portfolio</i></br></h1>
<p style="line-height: 2px;text-align: center;"><a href="aidancheung.htm"><img src="home.png" width="545" height="45" title="go to home" alt="Flower"></a><br><a href="https://www.google.com/"><img src="portfolio.png" width="545" height="45" title="go to portfolio" alt="Flower"></a></br><br><a href="https://www.google.com/"><img src="about.png" width="545" height="45" title="go to about" alt="Flower"></a></br></p>
<div class="bottom">
<img class="bottom" src="bottom.png" alt="Bottom Building">
</div>
</html>
```

Update: "added full code because some people asked to see it

Comment: Can you add your html?

Comment: Can you provide the complete HTML and CSS code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your starting position is top:275px then you must end the same position to your expect output. I alter your code little bit. Try this

```
     .bottom {
        position: absolute;
        top: 275px;
    }
    .bottom:hover img {
     position: absolute;
        -webkit-animation: floatBubble 2s  normal ease-out;
        animation: floatBubble 2s normal ease-out;
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

    }
    @-webkit-keyframes floatBubble {
        0% {
            top:275px;
        }
        50%{
           top: 500px;
        }
        100% {
            top:275px;
        }
    }
    @keyframes floatBubble {
        0% {
            top:275px;
        }
        50%{
           top: 500px;
        }
        100% {
            top:275px;
        }
    }
```

I hope this is help for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help but is there any way for the animation to end and stay in place ?